# Retornar tabla detalle mediante AJAX

Tags: jquery

Estoy diseñando una aplicacion dinamica, es decir un local tiene distintos envases con precios.
Hay 7 canillas con un barril de donde se sacan dos medidas cuarto y medio litro para vender:

```js
$.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/venta/procesoventa.php",
                data:{"accion":"lcanillas"},
      

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
       
                   $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (index, item) {
               medidas=Obtenerprecios(item.idbarril);
                    $.each(medidas,function (index,item){
                      var fila='<tr>'+
    
    '<td>'+item.descripcion+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+item.precio+'</td></tr>';
                     cm=cm+fila;   
                    });
                 
         var contenido='<div class="col-sm-4" > '+
         '<div class="panel panel-danger">'+
          '<div class="panel-heading">CANILLA '+item.idcanilla+'</div>'+
          '<div class="panel-body">'+
        '<table class="canilla">'+
   ' <thead>'+
    '<th></th>'+
    '<th>Valor</th>'+
    '<th>Accion</th>'+
    '</thead>'+
    '<tbody>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td>Estado</td>'+
    '<td>'+item.estado+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+cm
    +'<td><input type="button" id="Confirmar" value="Confirmar" class="btn btn-primary" /></td>'
  
  
   ' </tbody>'+
  '</table>'+
      '     </div></div></div> ' +
      '  </div>';
      $(contenido).appendTo("#canilla1");
      cm="";
                });

                }
 
});
```

Con el codigo de arriba me aparecen bien las canillas, pero el caso es que cada canilla esta asociada  acada medida existente en otra tabla.
Entonces como veran dentro del each llamo a otra funcion, y haciendo un console.log si obtengo los precios como corresponde pero me muestra undefined:

```js
 function Obtenerprecios(idbarril) {
 return $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/venta/procesoventa.php",
                data:{"accion":"medidas","idb":idbarril},
      

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(data)
            {

            }
            });}
```

La verdad no se que estoy haciendo mal o de que otra forma retornar la data de la funcion.
el return ajax devuelve
Object { readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(), statusCode: statusCode(), abort: abort(), state: state(), always: always(), catch: catch(), … } indexventa.js:25:14
Y en responseText estan los datos pero como podria leerlo?

Comment: ¿Has debugeado para ver qué te está devolviendo en la variable data?

Comment: si si..tal como dije en la pregunta. Hasta data dentro de la funcion llega todo bien..pero no esta pasando a la funcion principal.

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta ni dónde está fallando el código. Nunca es una buena idea hacer una petición Ajax dentro de un `each` que ocurre dentro de otra petición Ajax (si hay 100 iteracciones, ¡100 peticiones!). De ser obligatorio, reúne todos los datos que necesites haciendo primero las peticiones Ajax y luego con los datos reunidos construye el contenido. Aunque aquí lo mejor sería traer todos los datos de una vez en una sola petición: ahorras recursos, tiempo, etc. Es como si pudiendo traer dos productos en un solo viaje optases por hacer ¡`n` viajes! innecesariamente. ¿Por qué?

Comment: Lo q ocurre que tenemos 7 canillas con un barril cada una..por ende un tipo de cerveza distinto..entonces el precio de la medida depende del barril..la idea es listar todas las canillas xon sus tres precios: cuarto medio y entero.

Comment: Por eso queria consultar la canilla y pasar el idbarril a un metodo que me traiga los 3 precios de la tabla varios a varios para ese barril

Comment: Pero tú puedes traer toda la información en una sola consulta, uniendo las tablas mediante `JOIN`. No veo por qué haya que hacer otras consultas, y además dentro de un `each` que está dentro de una petición Ajax. No me parece para nada una buena idea, y mucho menos pudiendo hacer todo de una vez en una sola petición. Lo único que justificaría varias peticiones es que haya algún elemento desconocido que dependa de una 1ª petición y no es el caso aquí.

Comment: A lo que se refieren los compañeros es que desde el servidor debes enviar toda la información completa, aunque tengas que hacer iteraciones antes de mostrar el JSON. Es decir, justo lo que estás haciendo ahorita pero con consultas a la base de datos (No es lo más eficiente pero es menos que hacer una conexión por cada producto).
Ya con ese JSON puedes hacer la iteración sin consultas extra.
PD: Añade también `dataType: "json"` a tu `$.ajax`  para evitar el `JSON.parse`

Comment: Entiendo perfecto..es tema nuevo para mi..muchas gracias. Voy a intentar